# how to load raster image in leaflet?

Tags: raster, leaflet, basemap

I want to load a raster base layer in leaflet because the base layer usually needs an internet connection I want to load the raster offline .

Comment: I found how to do it you have to build firstly the mbtile with tilemille the raster of different zoom and devided in small squares here an explanation. https://youtu.be/DSu8BYtuWMU

Comment: Which raster base layer do you want to load? Will you use a LAN server for it, will you be restricted by storage in a mobilde device?

Comment: In mobile atlas creator I create sqlite mbties after i build the png tiles and thats all .

Comment: Open Street Map